# coupon not applying for subtotal more than 1100

Tags: magento-1.9

we want to apply coupon code

1)for all products with **price 499**

2) **except** some products which have particular **price as 299, 998, 999**.

3)**except** Products which are in **category id 6475**

so i am trying shopping cart price rule as below.

**issue** : **its not applying discount if subtotal is greater than 1100**

[image]

Also i tried like below image :

[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: is there any other shopping cart price rule that conflict with this rule

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara yes, we have lot of other shopping cart price rule and i set this rule for last `priority` and coupon code is different for all.....

Comment: 499  is including tax or excluding

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara no tax in site.....

Comment: then i dont know the answer i have same issue but it's problem with tax

Comment: you are not using special prices, aren't you? because rules don't apply to special prices

Comment: @AlessandroRonchi No, we are not using special prices for those products......

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara you are right, we have another rule that was having higher priority than this rule, so that was overriding this rule , so please post your comment as answer......

Comment: @AlessandroRonchi Thanks for your support, i got solution......

Comment: Good to know, please share it here so that others with same issue could benefit from that. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be There are any other shopping cart price rule which have higher priority then your current rule so may be they conflict with this rule.

**Try to find other rule and change priority**

Comment: My shopping cart price rule apply based on subtotal how can i change to products price? because my cart consisting not discount products also but the rule apply based on subtotal. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your coupon condition is working

Goto Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products)

Select condtion like

[image]

Comment: Thanks, please check `Edit` part in question, i did't set conditions like that......

Comment: using your idea, i added one more condition `Subtotal  greater than  1` as in image   http://prnt.sc/e9d753 , but still same issue.....

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got solution, but its really a great pleasure to see  your answer on my post..... i hope you will post more answers on my questions in future too :)

Comment: @BabyinMagento how to restrict shopping cart price rule apply on subtotal, i need rule apply based on products price.

Comment: @zus feel free to post new question......

Comment: @BabyinMagento I cant able to do new post, some issue in new post, can u help me here and in future i will post as new one and will let you know.

Comment: @zus create new `shopping cart price rule` & select `subtotal is` under `conditions.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Now my shopping cart price rule 20% discount apply on my subtotal, the non discount products also exits in cart, so this is not good, right? how can i solve this error?

Comment: @zus not an error,  so you want to give discount based on particular products ? than try for catalog price rules......

Comment: @BabyinMagento Screenshot :   FYI      https://snag.gy/lMtjEP.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84316/discussion-between-zus-and-baby-in-magento).